# The problem after upgraded newtonjson from 4.5.6 to 4.6.8+(now 13.0.1) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, json.net

I had asp.net mvc project and used newtonjson 4.5.6.
I tried to upgraded newtonjson from 4.5.6 to 13.0.1 so I had some problems.
I called api on javascript and got json data.
Everything is working on newtonjson 4.5.6 but some field in json is missing on newtonjson 4.6.8+(now 13.0.1).

- ProductSettingsViewModel.cs

```
 [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false)]
 public virtual bool DefaultSelected { get; set; }
```

- ProductSettings.cs

```
public bool DefaultSelected { get; set; }
```

- JS

```
var BaseGroupViewModel = function (data, configuratorVM) {
    $.each(self.options, function (i, option) {
        if (option.type() === 'Simple') {
            hasSimpleOptions = true;
            if (option.defaultSelected()) {                
                self.selected(self.options[i]);
                self.options[i].isSelected(true);
                hasDefault = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Please help me what is problem.

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake. 
I updated my code again. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] showing how to reproduce the problem?  The raw JSON plus your `ProductSettingsViewModel` and `ProductSettings` would help.  And what do you mean that the *field in json is missing*?  Do you mean that your JS code fails to serialize it?  Or that your c# code fails to deserialize it?